# Finding different lines between 2 HTML files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to find the difference between 2 txt files that contain HTML code, tried the difflib module but delta stays 0 no matter what I try.
I need to find how many lines are different from the total HTML code

thanks!

```
import difflib
count = 0
count2 = 0
delta = 0 
f = open('C\html1.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('C\html2.txt', 'r')
for i in f2:
    count2 += 1
for i in f:
    count += 1
diff = difflib.udiff = difflib.unified_diff(
            f.readlines(),
           f2.readlines(),
           fromfile='C\html1.txt',
            tofile='C\html2.txt',
       )
for line in diff:
    delta +=1
print delta

print count
per = (delta * 100) / count
```

Comment: You are iterating through `f` and `f2` to increment `count` and `count2`, making the position of the files at the end. When doing `readlines`, they are both empty lists. do `f.seek(0)` and `f2.seek(0)` to reset the position of the files back to the top

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as @wondercricket pointed out that the file pointers are already at EOF.

One way to solve this would be to call

`f.seek(0)` and `f2.seek(0)` to move the file pointer to the beginning of file before calculating the diff